# specifying the correct path of xsl file inside jar

Tags: java, xslt, spring-boot

I have an `XSL` file located inside `src/main/java` folder inside a package:

```
eu.deniss.report.view.xslt
```

I have used this to get the file location:

```
String location = './src/main/java/eu/deniss/report/view/xslt/'
```

While this runs fine when ran from IDE, when a `.jar` is created I get an error, that this file cannot be found.

What would be the correct path / way to call this xsl file, when my application is packaged as a `.jar` This application uses Spring Boot.

EDIT:

This is how I load the xslt file:

```
String xslFileForProcessing = "someFile.xslt";

File xsltFile = new File(xslFileProperties.getLocation() + xslFileForProcessing);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
```

Comment: `src/main/java` is a source folder from maven convention, it won't be present in the generated jar.

Comment: @MedhiRedjem and what would be the correct way of calling this file from inside the jar?

Comment: it depends on how you try to load your xsl template, add the snippet to your question.

Comment: @MedhiRedjem updated the initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `InputStream` as a parameter for the instance of `StreamSource`. You will be able to load resources available in your classpath easily :

```
final InputStream xsltStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/eu/deniss/report/view/xslt/someFile.xslt");

Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsltStream);

// for performance optimizations  
Templates cached = factory.newTemplates(xsltSource);
Transformer transformer = cached.newTransformer();
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try!

Comment: not working for me .. if possible, can you provide a more detailed example? I have my xslt under resources...